# Cross-AppDomain call performance with complex objects

Tags: c#, performance, api-design, appdomain

The app I'm working on allows users to provide their own code, which they build against an API that we have provided. We've recently moved the execution of user code to a separate AppDomain for security reasons. The API we provide passes the consumer an object graph (POCO) containing 100k+ objects. When this object passes the AppDomain boundary, all this data is serialized / deserialized using BinaryFormatter.

- BinaryFormatter is [slow](https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2017/04/23/the-definitive-serialization-performance-guide/) - O(n²) - it's not unusual for the serializer to take 1+ minute for serialization / deserialization.
- We can't change the API without causing a lot of breakage, so we're most likely stuck with it.

So far I've tried the following:

- Mark the model that's passed as `MarshalByRefObject`. This causes even more degradation, as for every property access on the model, all that property's data is serialized; causing additional serialization/deserialization overhead.
- Box/Unbox the model that's passed with a container that uses MessagePack / Protobuf-net for serialization. In my unit tests, the serialization performs much better (e.g. 60 -> 5 seconds). However when actually using it in the restricted AppDomain, deserialization fails because of security restrictions.

Some thoughts:

- The user's code is only called once with the big model, so it is serialized / deserialized only once.
- The data in the model originates from a Mongo database. The data is fetched from the database in a few seconds or less.
- I've been thinking about fetching the data from Mongo within the restricted AppDomain, however that probably requires lifting some restrictions and might cause security problems.
- I own the object in the client AppDomain that's proxied into the server AppDomain. This object then calls the user's code (through a RazorEngine template).

So my question is, what can I do to improve the performance of calling the user's code, while maintaining the current API and keep the separation provided by the secondary AppDomain?

Comment: "Deserialization fails because of security restrictions." How so? Deserializing flat data shouldn't be subject to any restrictions -- it is in principle always possible to do. This should be an artifact of how the deserialization works (does it try to instantiate classes from the other domain)? I can't imagine what kind of security restrictions would prevent this, at least not the kind that are actually necessary. Note that the problem is not really different (and could in fact be implemented as) passing data between completely separate processes, rather than just separated domains.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the exception I'm getting is "Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.". The stack trace points to somewhere inside either MessagePack / Protobuf-net.

Comment: Hi; serialization library author here: indeed, by default, most serialization libraries do a *lot* of poking around with reflection - enough to trigger this kind of warning. There are ways of avoiding that, but ... it is a lot of work (and frankly I'm still working on ways of making it easier / friendlier; I don't have that ready to roll today). If I had this scenario, I'd be investigating how to grant security permissions *to the specific assembly* (or to the strong-name key of the library), such that you trust the *library* without trusting the user code

Comment: It's probably stumbling up against `ReflectionPermission`([see also](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/security-considerations-for-reflection)), but generating code at runtime is available even to non-privileged code (since .NET 2 SP1), so I'm not clear what approach they're using.

Comment: @JeroenMostert probably things like `BindingFlags.NonPublic`, which... yeah, I do that *a lot*

Comment: @bouke as a side note: I don't think it is going to be something I can adequately address in a Stack Overflow post, but if the scenario is something that can be demonstrated in a "minimal repro" style, it *is* something that I'd be more than willing to look at as a github investigation (in my case, against protobuf-net), to see if we can find ways of making it work (perhaps by identifying the bits that are throwing, and avoiding the problematic scenarios - presumably, as said, `BindingFlags.NonPublic` etc)

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you so much for the information; I'll try a few different techniques from the comments you and Jeroen posted, and otherwise try and come up with a minimal repro.

Comment: The odds that you use the AppDomain correctly are rather low.  It is not the de/serialization of an object that is risky, it is what happens next.  Calling methods.  *That* code needs to live in the AD as well.  At which point the AD transition can't slow down anything anymore since everything happens in the AD.  Do be very careful with security theater, it is much more dangerous than regular code.